# .htaccess rewrite underscores to hypens, strip extension, & remove trailing underscores

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm converting my blog from movable type to wordpress.There are several thousand entries, and thankfully I am able to keep (almost) the same permalinks.

I know that with some clever `.htaccess` wizardry, I should be able to redirect my URLs, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the statement(s) should be.I have over 20,000 entries, so redirects on individual pages is not ideal.

Here's what I need to do:

I have a bunch of URLs like this:

http://example.com/posttype/2013/05/04/story_name_and_such_.php

I need to :

```
if(extension is .php) {
  1. Convert underscores to hypens in the filename.
  2. Remove the file extension.
  3. Remove trailing hypens.
}
```

The above would end up as such:

http://example.com/posttype/2013/05/04/story-name-and-such

Anyone done something similar to this?  I could really use the help on this one!

Comment: Wordpress give you a guide to migrating content - there are some suggestions there for dealing with the redirection. The page is at http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_from_Movable_Type_to_WordPress

Comment: @Phil why is `RewriteRule` overkill compared to `RedirectMatch`?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)_(.+)\.php /$1-$2.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)_\.php /$1.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php /$1 [L,R=301]
```