# Codeigniter Change URL method name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in CI.

I want to change function name in addressbar url with `add_car` to `addcar`.

Actually my url is created as below

```
http://localhost/projectName/controller/add_car
```

But I want following in URL

```
http://localhost/projectName/controller/addcar
```

Is it possible? Please help me.

`[Note]` : My actual method name is `add_car`.

Comment: Go to `config/routes.php` and add `$route['addcar'] = "add_car" ;`

Comment: @Saty But I have lots of `controller` and lots of `method` in it then ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428134/codeigniter-routes-regex-using-dashes-in-controller-method-names)

Comment: @Saty Thanks for help I will try it

Comment: hei @Sadikhasan i was edit my answer.. you can map your method use car_lookup funtion.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by two methods

**Method 01**

Edit - `config/routes.php`

```
$route['controller/addcar'] = 'controller/add_car';
$route['controller/deletecar'] = 'controller/delete_car';
```

**output** - `www.exapmle.com/controller/addcar`

---

**Method 02**

change your controller function name as you like.

```
public function addcar($value='')
{
    # code...
}
public function deletecar($value='')
{
    # code...
}
```

**Output** -`www.exapmle.com/controller/addcar`

---

**Further Knowledge**

If you use `$route['addcar'] = 'controller/add_car';` URL looks like

```
www.exapmle.com/addcar
```

Comment: I tried your answer $route['controller/addcar'] = 'controller/add_car'; If I try www.mydomain.com/controller/addcar then it's working but I used before $route['(:any)'] = 'controller/$1';(remove the controller name) then its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change `add_car` function to `addcar` in your controller

```
function add_car(){
  //...
}
```

To

```
function addcar(){
          ^
  //...
}
```

Or in `routes.php`

```
$route['controller/add_car'] = "controller/addcar";
```

Comment: I do not want to change naming convention in controller. Its ok with underscore.

Comment: For every method I need to spechify its `route`?

Comment: Actually I want to change method name in URL address bar do not want to change actual method name.

Comment: use routes in that case.

Comment: But I have lots of `controller` and lots of `method` in it then ?

Comment: in that case, you have to go with `.htaccess`

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564065/htaccess-rewrite-underscores-to-hypens-strip-extension-remove-trailing-unde)

Comment: Thanks for help I will try it

Answer (score 1):

`$route['controller/([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)'] = "controller/$1$2";`

Above example will route every requested action containing '_' between two strings to action/method without the '_'.

More about Code Igniter regular expression routes:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on your route:

```
$route['addcar'] = 'Add_car/index';
$route['addcar/(:any)'] = 'Add_car/car_lookup/$1';
```

and your controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Add_car extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function car_lookup($method = NULL)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index(); // call default index
    }
}

public function index()
{
    echo "index";
}


public function method_a()
{
    echo "aaaaa";
}

public function method_b()
{
    echo "bbbbb";
}
}
```

Comment: For every method I need to spechify its `route`?

Comment: if you use this. you will not need to define new route every time your add new method.